# Vbscript to open a shared file in read/write mode for a particular username and keep the other users have the permission to open read only mode

Tags: excel, vbscript, file-permissions, readonly, shared

I am working on a vbscript that access a shared excel file that is stored in shared path.First Vbscript should check, if the file is used by someone else(Other users who have access to that shared file) or not.
If somebody kept the file already in open state vbscript should forcefully release their read-write access and give them read-only access. Whenever the vbscript is running in user machine it should make the user read-write access to that particular file and the other users permission should be read-only.

There should be another vbscript to remove all the restrictions that have made by using the above vbscript.

```
Sub wkbk_open()

    wkbk_name = "Project List LIVE.xlsm"
    wkbk_lock_file_path = "X:\~$" & wkbk_name

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    If objFSO.FileExists(wkbk_lock_file_path) Then
        Debug.Print "The file is locked by " & GetFileOwner(wkbk_lock_file_path)
        Debug.Print "The file is locked by " & GetFileOwner2(wkbk_lock_file_path)
    Else
        Debug.Print "The file is available"
    End If

End Sub

Function GetFileOwner(strFileName)
    'http://www.vbsedit.com/scripts/security/ownership/scr_1386.asp
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:")
    Set objFileSecuritySettings = _
    objWMIService.Get("Win32_LogicalFileSecuritySetting='" & strFileName & "'")
    intRetVal = objFileSecuritySettings.GetSecurityDescriptor(objSD)

    If intRetVal = 0 Then
       GetFileOwner = objSD.Owner.Name
    Else
       GetFileOwner = "Unknown"
    End If
End Function

Function GetFileOwner2(strFileName) As String

'On Error Resume Next
Dim secUtil As Object
Dim secDesc As Object
Set secUtil = CreateObject("ADsSecurityUtility")
Set secDesc = secUtil.GetSecurityDescriptor(strFileName, 1, 1)
GetFileOwner2 = secDesc.Owner
End Function
```

Comment: This question has [already been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62228899/692942), update the question instead of adding a new one. If it's been closed it will be re-opened if people feel it has enough information.

Comment: Duplicate of [Vbscript to open a shared file in read/write mode for a particular username and keep the other users permission to open read only mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62228899/vbscript-to-open-a-shared-file-in-read-write-mode-for-a-particular-username-and)

Comment: I had edited the query already ,still it says closed

Comment: It was last [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62228899/revisions) 21 hours ago and you haven't included the code as you have in this duplicate post. Go back and edit that question and it will be reviewed.

Comment: Query has been updated